# how to create a complex javascript structure

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to create a structure like that:

```
[{title:'Imágenes', extensions:'jpg,gif,png'}, {title:'Todos', extensions:'*'}]
```

but i need to create it from a string, in this way (in "js+jquery+php rare mode"):

```
items = 'Imágenes jpg,gif,png|Todos *'.split('|').each(function() {
  list(title, ext) = explode(' ', $this);
  filters[] = array('title' => title, 'ext' => ext);
});
```

i found structures like:

```
var theStatus = new Object();
function testIt() {
  theStatus.Home = 'mouseover';
  theStatus['Place'] = 'click';
  for (var i in theStatus)
  {
    alert('theStatus[\''+i+'\'] is ' + theStatus[i])
  }
}
```

and like:

```
$.alerts = {
  verticalOffset: -75,
  horizontalOffset: 0,
  repositionOnResize: true,
  overlayOpacity: .01,
  overlayColor: '#FFF'
}
```

but i cant do nothing functional.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```
items = 'Imágenes jpg,gif,png|Todos *'.split("|").map(function (itemString) {
    var parts =  itemString.split(" ");
    return { title: parts[0], extensions: parts[1] };
});
```

Or you can do this if you use jQuery and need to support older browsers:

```
items = $.map('Imágenes jpg,gif,png|Todos *'.split("|"), function () {
    var parts =  this.split(" ");
    return { title: parts[0], extensions: parts[1] };
});
```

Comment: You forgot the `.split('|')` on the first line, and the native Javascript `Array.map()` function is only compatible with newer browsers.

Comment: Fixed. And it is super easy to add map, reduce etc. to the Array prototype in browsers that don't support them natively. Those methods are so useful, that I would recommend anyone to always do that. There's a project on GitHub called ES5 Shim that does just that.

Comment: this way works too, and seems to be a bit more cool :) i'll try the "map" way in various browsers so i can see if they support this, anyway, the GregL's way will be a generic solution for me :) thanks from spain!!

Comment: map doesn't work in IE8 and below. If you need to support that, you can either use the jQuery solution or you can include https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim or you can use GregL's solution.

Comment: ok, i only need ff, chrome y safari (for the designers), the jquery variant is the best for me, es5-shim is more than i need. In the other hand, i save this question and es5-shim link for the future. i had a problem, now i have a solution. thanks very much again!

Answer (score 1):

Your pseudocode is close.

Try the following vanilla javascript:

```
var str = 'Imágenes jpg,gif,png|Todos *';
var objs = str.split('|');
var objects = [];
for (var i = 0; i < objs.length; i++) {
    var parts = objs[i].split(' ');
    objects.push({ title: parts[0], extensions: parts[1] });
}
// objects is now an array of custom objects in the format you specified.
```